# The cubic equation using alined x?

Tags: math-mode, equations, environments

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}% load the AMS symbols
\parskip=0pt

\begin{document}

  \centerline{\Large\sffamily The cubic formula}\bigskip

%% Do not change anything above this line!

  Suppose that $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$, for $a, b, c, d\in\mathbb{R}$.\\
Then
\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{-b}{3a} + \sqrt[3]{\alpha + \sqrt{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{3}}} 
+ \sqrt[3]{\alpha -\sqrt{\alpha^{2}+ \beta^{3}}} , \tag{1}\\
\intertext{where}
\alpha & = -\frac{b^3}{27a^3}+ \frac{bc}{6a^2} - \frac{d}{2a} , \\
\beta &= \frac{c}{3a} - \frac{b^2}{9a^2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

But i still have confusion about the hint:

1. You only need two `\notag` commands to remove the equations numbers from the two equations `\alpha=...` and `\beta=...`. The `\notag` commands should go before the end of the line that you want to suppress the equation number from and so, in particular, before the new line separator `\\` for this line`\\`
2. Please check your punctuation. There should be a comma AND a space before the word 'for', a space and a full-stop before 'Then',  and each line of the equation should end in either a comma or full-stop. Note that punctuation should always be OUTSIDE of mathematics mode
3. You want an equation number for the equation `x=...` so you should use an `align` environment
4. You need to add the opening sentence `Suppose that...` (which i definitely write in the code!)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The hints you received are correct. Also ``\\`` before “Then” should be removed.

Comment: What is your question? What, exactly, are you trying to achieve? If you want the equation `x = ...` numbered but each of the equations `\alpha =` and `\beta = ` unnumbered, then what you have is correct. (Note: I think "for" is ambiguous here" and would be better replace by "where".)